# Oracle SQL Developer: Exporting to XML without CDATA

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Recently started using Oracle SQL Developer. I have successfully run queries and exported results to XML (encoding='UTF-8').  e.g.

```
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ACCOUNTID"><![CDATA[1]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ADDRLINE1"><![CDATA[XYZ company]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ADDRLINE2"><![CDATA[]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ADDRLINE3"><![CDATA[999 6th AVENUE]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ADDRLINE4"><![CDATA[NEW YORK]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ADDRLINE5"><![CDATA[NEW YORK, NY 10112]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="COUNTRY"><![CDATA[USA]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
```

My question: is there a way to export without the CDATA defs?  i.e. it's "simple" data and what I want/need is:

```
<Row>
    <X>1</X>
    <ACCOUNTID>1</ACCOUNTID>
    <ADDRLINE1>XYZ company</ADDRLINE1>
    <ADDRLINE2/>
    <ADDRLINE3>999 6th AVENUE </ADDRLINE3>
    <ADDRLINE4>NEW YORK</ADDRLINE4>
    <ADDRLINE5>NEW YORK, NY 10112</ADDRLINE5>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
</Row>
```

Looked through preferences and could not find anything useful.  I saw a very old post stating that the resultant XML was generated via XSL but I couldn't find any XSL.

Has anyone ever done this or have any ideas?

Comment: Is another way of generating XML from the database an option? Take a look at xmlelement

Comment: this has been requested 6 years ago - but not available yet. Read here - https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=370848

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could get ith a query was this:

(I have used a `WITH` clause to generate the table record)

```
WITH t
  AS (SELECT '1' AS x,
             '1' AS accountid,
             'XYZ company' AS addrline1,
             NULL AS addrline2,
             '999 6th AVENUE' AS addrline3,
             'NEW YORK' AS addrline4,
             'NEW YORK, NY 10112' AS addrline5,
             'USA' AS country
        FROM dual)
SELECT xmlelement("row",
          xmlelement(x,x),
          xmlelement(accountid,accountid),
          xmlelement(addrline1,addrline1),
          xmlelement(addrline2,addrline2),
          xmlelement(addrline3,addrline3),
          xmlelement(addrline4,addrline4),
          xmlelement(addrline5,addrline5),
          xmlelement(country,country)
       )
  FROM t;
```

The output generated was:

```
<row>
  <X>1</X>
  <ACCOUNTID>1</ACCOUNTID>
  <ADDRLINE1>XYZ company</ADDRLINE1>
  <ADDRLINE2></ADDRLINE2>
  <ADDRLINE3>999 6th AVENUE</ADDRLINE3>
  <ADDRLINE4>NEW YORK</ADDRLINE4>
  <ADDRLINE5>NEW YORK, NY 10112</ADDRLINE5>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
</row>
```

Hope it helps...